# Why will my code not open a window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, window, pylance

It's supposed to just open the window so far, but during testing, it wouldn't open the window, although no errors are displayed.

I've already tried using "pygame.disply.flip()" instead of update but that changed nothing.
I get this in the terminal too:
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
and that's it.

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

class DrawInformation:
    BLACK = 0, 0, 0
    WHITE = 255, 255, 255
    GREEN = 0, 255, 0 
    RED = 255, 0, 0
    GREY = 128, 128, 128
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = WHITE

    SIDE_PAD = 100
    TOP_PAD = 150

    def __init__(self, width, height, lst):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sorting Algorithm Visualization")
        self.set_list(lst)

    def set_list(self, lst):
        self.list = lst
        self.min_val = min(lst)
        self.max_val = max(lst)

        self.block_width = round((self.width - self.SIDE_PAD) / len(lst))
        self.block_height = round((self.height - self.TOP_PAD) / (self.max_val - self.min_val))
        self.start_x = self.SIDE_PAD // 2

def generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val):
    lst = []

    for _ in range(n):
        val = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
        lst.append(val)
    
    return lst

def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    n = 50
    min_val = 0
    max_val = 100


    lst = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val)
    draw_info = DrawInformation(800, 600, lst)

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
    pygame.quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

This is what I have so far ... it's also saying that "draw_info" is not accessed by pylance and idk why??

Comment: Due to the indentation "main()" is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

is intended so is inside the `def main()`
so it is not running when the program starts.

here's the corrected code.

```
import random

pygame.init()

class DrawInformation:
    BLACK = 0, 0, 0
    WHITE = 255, 255, 255
    GREEN = 0, 255, 0 
    RED = 255, 0, 0
    GREY = 128, 128, 128
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = WHITE

    SIDE_PAD = 100
    TOP_PAD = 150

    def __init__(self, width, height, lst):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sorting Algorithm Visualization")
        self.set_list(lst)

    def set_list(self, lst):
        self.list = lst
        self.min_val = min(lst)
        self.max_val = max(lst)

        self.block_width = round((self.width - self.SIDE_PAD) / len(lst))
        self.block_height = round((self.height - self.TOP_PAD) / (self.max_val - self.min_val))
        self.start_x = self.SIDE_PAD // 2

def generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val):
    lst = []

    for _ in range(n):
        val = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
        lst.append(val)
    
    return lst

def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    n = 50
    min_val = 0
    max_val = 100


    lst = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val)
    draw_info = DrawInformation(800, 600, lst)

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```